# How to stop windows from installing Realtek drivers

Tags: windows-10

I have problem in my laptop about headphone detection and no sound after cold boot. After trying Realtek HD audio R2.81, R2.81 and UAD, I found that none of them works properly, whereas surprisingly, Microsoft default audio device driver works fine. Now the problem becomes I can't keep Windows from replacing it by Realtek Scraps at every boot.
Methods I've tried:

Disabling "automatically update drivers from manufacturer etc, etc..." from system advance settings, control panel. I've set it to NO.

Preventing Device driver installation from group policy editor for that specific hardware ID.

I don't want to install/ uninstall/ reinstall anything from Realtek, whatever version, wherever available. (I have had enough with them, installed different drivers 30+ times till now.)

It would be fine to edit registry or even delete system files from windows to remove those drivers if necessary.

OS: Windows 10 Home 1909 Build: 18363.720
      Machine: Lenovo Ideapad 530s 15IKB

Comment: Have you tried the tool designed to hide driver updates?  This tool can be found on the Microsoft website.

Comment: You can also search for the Realtek service in question in the Service tab in Task Manager, and set it to "Disabled", then reboot. Disable Fast Startup before you restart your PC; you can enable it back after your PC has finished restarting if you want.

Comment: @Ramhound, Would you please point a source to that? I didn't find anything like that.

Comment: @Didier When I uninstall the driver, there is no related service left. When windows reinstall them, they come back.

Comment: @Shounak I suspect that Ramhound meant [How to temporarily prevent a driver update from reinstalling in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/3073930/how-to-temporarily-prevent-a-driver-update-from-reinstalling-in-window) - found by searching for "hide driver updates".

Comment: @Andrew - Yes; Exactly

Comment: Shounak, it you disable the service THEN uninstall the driver, it won't come back, otherwise, Windows will try to push it to you with every update, even if you order it not to. The tool Ramhound pointed you to usually works, but for some essential parts of your PC such as network adapters, graphics cards and the like, Windows will always try to update drivers anyway. You can also try to install a third-party software that'll give you access to Group Policies on your PC, and set a GPO there to prevent drivers from being updated automatically, leaving you the option to do so manually.

Comment: You can try this one: https://github.com/Fleex255/PolicyPlus. I've used it on Windows 10 Home computers several times to set GPOs in place, and it's reliable.

Comment: Templates link to Didier's comment link>>>>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3087759/how-to-create-and-manage-the-central-store-for-group-policy-administra

Comment: That's right, thanks Moab! You can download them directly from PolicyPlus.

Comment: @Didier I tried editing group policy for hardware id, GUID and instance id. I did it with the MS inbuilt one.(Enabled it before...) I tried policy plus also. :-) It shows them enabled. Anyway, windows just ignore them I think.

Comment: @Didier Yes, I disabled the service BEFORE I uninstall, but it gets enabled and automatic after windows reinstall the scrap.

Comment: Open Regedit as admin (either via Command Line or by Shift-clicking the OK button in the Run box), go to \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\name_of_the_service, and in the right pane, check for an entry called "Owner". There should be a file name with a .inf extension. After stopping the service (from Services or in CLI as admin, with the "sc stop name_of_the_service" command), double-click the entry in Regedit, and delete the name of the owner, then restart your PC.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a manual selection of the driver from the device manager.

It starts with update driver, browser from my computer, select driver manually, select the wimdows generic driver and restart the PC.

Comment: The downvotes make me want to not help anymore, but still lets try and give a chance. Since this is your only option, follow this video. It should permanently replace your driver with the generic one. The other option is to search in driverscape.com for the correct driver and before that install all updates on Windows. including the latest net framework from google.com. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aZDGZbV3Vvs

Comment: I've tried that before, it didn't help. Anyway, don't get disheartened, despite it didn't help me, it would surely help someone else.

Comment: I have set drivers like this before, something else is wrong. I suggest trying these drivers:
Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller and
Realtek High Definition Audio
https://www.driverscape.com/manufacturers/lenovo/laptops-desktops/lenovo-ideapad-u510/110788